# trajectory polinomial fiting

Tags: polynomials

assume we have a sequence of points on the 2D plane, we know the order of points but not the time gap between them.

I want to approximate this trajectory with 2 polynomials x(t) and y(t), but i  don't know what I should get as  `t`? the number of the point? the accumulated distance between points? I tried both of this options and I feel I am doing something wrong both times.

Any suggestion what should we take as `t` here?

Comment: The suggestion is to raise the question on a concrete manner, that is to edit a numerical example.

Comment: Can you make any reasonable assumptions about the speed along the trajectory or the process which chose the points.

Comment: @user121049 Yes, I  know  the  speed  is about  constant, but there can    be missing points

Comment: The of time of travel between points is (roughly) proportional to the Pythagorean distance between points. It does not matter that there are points missing, just accumulate the time between points. This is not of course real time, it is time in some unknown units that depends on the speed.

Comment: In this video we can learn to make a kinetic analysis of a mechanical arm applying polynomial interpolation
https://youtu.be/v9p_2utyjgw